# Query realtime data from firestore with dynamic input using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

So far I have tried this, where I'm able to get all data but I want only data corresponding to the input which is selected by user. I'm new to this, any suggestions.

component.html :--

```
<label>Name:</label>
    <select [(ngModel)] = "selectedLevel" (change)="selected()">
      <option *ngFor="let post of posts | async"  [ngValue]="post">{{post.user}} 
      </option>
    </select>
```

Component.ts :--

```
 export interface Post{
  user: string;
  callType : string;
  callDuration: string;
  callTime : string;
} 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent {
  constructor (private afs:AngularFirestore){
  }
  public CallDetails: object = []; 
public calls =[];

postsCol: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>
posts: Observable<Post[]>

selectedLevel;
  ngOnInit(){

    this.postsCol = this.afs.collection<Post>('acb', ref => ref.orderBy('user', 'asc'));
    this.posts = this.postsCol.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      })
    })
     return this.posts;
  }
```

[This is the format of output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoKDW.png)

Comment: What are you getting now that isn't working?

Comment: I'm getting full data but I want only that data which corresponds to number selected by user from dropdown of number list .

Comment: You can only retrieve full documents, rather than doing something like SQL's `select id from users`, it's more equivalent to `select * from users`

Comment: I think sql query not works on firestore